# PowerShell : How to run a script by double clicking on it ? (without 'Run with Powershell')

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, msgbox

[EDIT BELOW : The problem was not the MsgBox]

I got a problem : my MsgBox works fine when I run the code from ISE but does not show up when I execute it by double clicking on .ps1 file.

I tried all what internet could give me (on others forums and on StackOverflow too), that's why you'll see many useless lines (especially many AssemblyName) but I keep them in order to show you what I already tried.

Here is my code :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

$msgBody = @'
Hello.

Press OK to export.
'@
$msgTitle = 'Export to Google Drive' 
$msgButton = 'OKCancel'
$msgImage = 'Warning'

$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)

Write-Host "The user chose: $Result ["($result).value__"]"
```

Thanks for your time and help.

[EDIT]

I have some news : The problem was not the MsgBox, the .ps1 is just NOT running AT ALL when double clicking on it (or calling it with Windows Task Scheduler). I tested it with a simple Write-Host and it doesn't show up either.

What happens is that the Powershell execution window is just opening and closing real quick.

**I have an answer** for this problem (a bypass more precisely) that I posted as answer to my own post below.

As it's not a general solution to make a script run by double clicking on it, I keep this post opened if anyone has a real answer.

I know it's possible because I have many scripts that runs directly by double clicking on it (without shortcut either).

Comment: What _does_ happen? Error messages? PowerShell opening and closing real quick? Another application launching? Please be mindful only you can see your screen :)

Comment: The first line `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` is pointless, because when the execution policy prevents your script from running, it won't reach that line. If there actually is an execution policy issue, you either have to change execution policy globally, as an administrator, before running the script or modify the file type association of ".ps1" files to pass `-ExecutionPolicy` argument to PowerShell.exe.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sorry, Powershell is opening and closing real quick without executing the code (I tested it with a simple 'Write-Host')

Comment: Understood @zett42 but I have no admin rights (PC from work).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lucas-crespo-ferreira I got a solution, I bypass the problem by calling my script with .BAT and thanks to this, the script runs perfectly and the MsgBox shows up.

Here is the code to write in .BAT :

```
powershell -noexit "& ""C:\my_path\FolderName\YourPowerShellScriptName.ps1"""
```

Be sure to modify the path with your own.

I know it's not a general solution to make a script run by double clicking on it so I let this post opened.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).